# Is there way to keep delimiter while using php explode or other similar functions?

Tags: php

For example, I have an article should be splitted according to sentence boundary such as "`.`", "`?`", "`!`" and "`:`".

But as well all know, whether `preg_split` or `explode` function, they both remove the delimiter.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I can only come up with the code below, it works great though.

```
$content=preg_replace('/([\.\?\!\:])/',"\\1[D]",$content);
```

Thank you!!! Everyone. It is only five minutes for getting 3 answers! And I must apologize for not being able to see the PHP manual carefully before asking question. Sorry.

Comment: Better [mcve] here: [Split a text into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16377437/2943403)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag

For example

```
$parts = preg_split("/([\.\?\!\:])/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 28):

I feel this is worth adding. You can keep the delimiter in the "after" string by using [regex lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to split:

```
$input = "The address is http://stackoverflow.com/";
$parts = preg_split('@(?=http://)@', $input);
// $parts[1] is "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

And if the delimiter is of fixed length, you can keep the delimiter in the "before" part by using lookbehind:

```
$input = "The address is http://stackoverflow.com/";
$parts = preg_split('@(?<=http://)@', $input);
// $parts[0] is "The address is http://"
```

This solution is simpler and cleaner in most cases.

Comment: You can even use multiple delimiters like this: `preg_split('@(?=(http://|https://))@', $input)` (kept in "after")

Answer (score 19):

You can set the flag *PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE* when using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) and capture the delimiters too. Then you can take each pair of 2‍*n* and 2‍*n*+1 and put them back together:

```
$parts = preg_split('/([.?!:])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$sentences = [];
for ($i = 0, $n = count($parts) - 1; $i <= $n; $i += 2) {
    $sentences[] = $parts[$i] . ($parts[$i+1] ?? '');
}
```

Note to pack the splitting delimiter into a group, otherwise they won’t be captured.

Comment: Just what I wanted to do... but I was too laisy to type :-)

Comment: Note that this does not work when using non specific tokens, such as \d \s... they wouldn't be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Try [T-Regx](http://t-regx.com/)

```php
<?php
$parts = pattern('([.?!:])')->split($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing English sentences has a lot of nuance and fringe cases.  This makes crafting a perfect parser very difficult to do.  It is important to have sufficient test cases using your real project data to make sure that you are covering all scenarios.

There is no need to use lookarounds or capture groups for this task.  You simply match the punctuation symbol(s), then forget them with `\K`, then match one or more whitespace characters that occurs between sentences.  Using the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag prevents creating empty elements if your string starts with or ends with characters that satisfy the pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8pnJ0))

```
$str = 'Heading: This is a string. Very exciting! What do you think? ...one more thing, this is cool.';

var_export(
    preg_split('~[.?!:]+\K\s+~', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Heading:',
  1 => 'This is a string.',
  2 => 'Very exciting!',
  3 => 'What do you think?',
  4 => '...one more thing, this is cool.',
)
```