# I am trying to split/explode/preg_split a string but I want to keep the delimiter

Tags: php, regex, split, explode, preg-split

I am trying to split/explode/preg_split a string but I want to keep the delimiter example :

```
explode('/block/', '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4');
```

Expected result :

```
array('/block/2/page/2', '/block/3/page/4');
```

Not sure if I have to loop and then re-prefix the array values or if there is a cleaner way.

I have tried preg_split() with PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE but I get something along the lines of :

```
array('/block/, 2/page/2', '/block/, 3/page/4');
```

Which is not what I want. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to do it in one line or just do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there way to keep delimiter while using php explode or other similar functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938137/is-there-way-to-keep-delimiter-while-using-php-explode-or-other-similar-function)

Comment: I had already read that question, and I dont think it is a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) like so:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(\/block\/[0-9]+\/page\/[0-9]+)/', '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4', $matches);
var_dump( $matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "/block/2/page/2"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "/block/3/page/4"
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GbJOtW)

**Edit:** [This](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9w9HgX) is the best I could do with preg_split.

```
$array = preg_split('#(/block/)#', '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$result = array();
for( $i = 0, $count = count( $array); $i < $count; $i += 2)
{
    $result[] = $array[$i] . $array[$i + 1];   
}
```

It's not worth the overhead to use a regular expression if you still need to loop to prepend the delimiter. Just use explode and prepend the delimiter yourself:

```
$delimiter = '/block/'; $results = array();
foreach( explode( $delimiter, '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4') as $entry)
{
    if( !empty( $entry))
    {
        $results[] = $delimiter . $entry;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kqdi6E)

**Final Edit:** Solved! Here is the solution using one regex, `preg_split`, and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`

```
$regex = '#(/block/(?:\w+/?)+(?=/block/))#';
$flags = PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY;
preg_split( $regex, '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4', -1, $flags);
preg_split( $regex, '/block/2/page/2/order/title/sort/asc/block/3/page/4', -1, $flags);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "/block/2/page/2"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "/block/3/page/4"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "/block/2/page/2/order/title/sort/asc"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "/block/3/page/4"
}
```

[Final Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9lKvqx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem in my case is that dont know how many segments exist beforehand, 
example :

    explode('/block/', '/block/2/page/2/order/title/sort/asc/block/3/page/4');

expected result : 
array('/block/2/page/2/order/title/sort/asc', '/block/3/page/4');

Comment: @Purplefish32 - I've added a more detailed answer. Unfortunately I could not achieve the desired results using a single regex and reverted to prepending the delimiter.

Comment: Perfect, I finally went for the prepend delimiter method, works like a charm thank you to all that have answered

Comment: @Purplefish32 - My final edit is the perfect solution, using a single regex and `preg_split` to achieve the desired results exactly. Hope it helps, please let me know! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that:

```
explode('/block/', '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4');
```

Will result in:

```
array("", "2/page/2", "3/page/4");
```

You could use a `preg_match_all` like

```
preg_match_all(":(/block/.*?):", $string); // untested
```

But just prepending the delimiter is a much clearer solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, How would I go about prepending the delimiter ?

Comment: `preg_match_all(":(/block/.*?):", $string)` definitely does not work: https://3v4l.org/Whtkc and explode doesn't work as required.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a lookahead.  This will match a zero-width position in the string at each point of explosion.  To prevent splitting before the first occurrence, use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jMv1Q))

```
$str = '/block/2/page/2/block/3/page/4';

var_export(
    preg_split('~(?=/block/)~', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '/block/2/page/2',
  1 => '/block/3/page/4',
)
```