# Splitting html content by chapters

Tags: php, split

I got a html-string in a variable, which looks something like this:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
 Introduction
 <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
  <p>Always just one line</p>
  <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
  <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
 <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
  <p>Always just one line</p>
  <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
  <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>

<h1>Title 2</h1>
Introduction
 <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
  <p>Always just one line</p>
  <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
  <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
 <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
  <p>Always just one line</p>
  <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
  <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
```

For further processing I need these "blocks" in a variable (array). First of all the main-chapter which starts with a `<h1>` and goes to the next `<h1>` should be seperated.

I tried to use `explode()` with a delimiter `<h1` But that removes part of the tag itself.

And as a second step I also need to separate the chapter of each "block". At a last step I need to get the description of a chapter content.

I think the key is the first step: Split the complete thing into main-chapter into an array. After that I can process the "subblocks" in a foreach loop or something else with the same technique (I guess).

Comment: If you html-string has newline chars '\n' you can use explode with delimiter '\n'

Comment: So you used explode, but it removes the delimiter. Maybe the question "[Is there way to keep delimiter while using php explode or other similar functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938137/is-there-way-to-keep-delimiter-while-using-php-explode-or-other-similar-function)" is of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. No problem. Use `explode()` function. It removes `<h1` you can easily add `<h1` yourself like this:

```
<?php
$html = '<h1>Title 1</h1>
     Introduction
     <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
     <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>

    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    Introduction
     <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
     <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
    ';

$html = explode('<h1', $html);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($html) ; $i++) $html[$i] = '<h1' . $html[$i];
unset($html[0]); //if <h1 is on the beginning of string
print_r(var_dump($html));
```

BTW you can remove the first index if it's empty. (Because `<h1` is in the beginnig of your string) you can even add this in your `for`:

```
if ($html[$i] == '') unset($html[$i]);
```

**Answer to your comment:**

If you want to split `<h2` too, you can do the same thing again but with `h2` delimiter:

```
<?php
$html = '<h1>Title 1</h1>
     Introduction
     <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
     <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>

    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    Introduction
     <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
     <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
      <p>Always just one line</p>
      <p class="description">Some more text.</p>
      <p class="description">Maybe with multiple lines.</p>
    ';

$html = explode('<h1', $html);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($html) ; $i++) $html[$i] = '<h1' . $html[$i];

// h2:

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($html) ; $i++){
    $html[$i] = explode('<h2', $html[$i]);
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($html[$i]) ; $j++) if(strpos($html[$i][$j],'>') == 0) $html[$i][$j] = '<h2' . $html[$i][$j];
}
unset($html[0]);
print_r(var_dump($html));
```

Comment: Thanks. That really helps. How would you do the second split for &lt;h2 to get a multidimensional array? I mean the var html now has the main chapter - which works great. But I want to split the main chapter into the h2-chapter and put everything into one variable.

Comment: Really last question: How can I get the content/text of h1- or h2-tag? Just i.e. 'Title 2' or 'Chapter 1'.

Comment: @user3142695 You can iterate over all lines in array (or just in the `for`) and replace all `<h1` or `<h2` with `''` using the function `str-replace`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php it will do it fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you could `explode('\n', $string)` and then iterate over all lines, switching to the next chapter, if `strpos($line, '<h1>') !== false`.

However, you cannot generally extract html elements from a string using simple string tools. Try using [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead.

Comment: In this case it should be pretty straightforward.