# PHP: How to split a string at keyword

Tags: php, string, explode

I am trying to split a string at keyword *`"http://"`*.

```
explode("http://", $input);
```

This doesn't work for me because it does not only split the `$input` but it also deletes *`"http://"`* from the string, which i don't want to happen.

What is the most effecient and fast way of doing this ? 
I didn't find any function for this so far.

Comment: where are the test cases? and the attempt?, whats the context of this anyway

Comment: what do you mean test cases ? `explode("http://", "http://1.1http://2.2");`  gives me `1.1` and `2.2` , i want to get `http://1.1` and `http://2.2`  was it really not clear enough ?

Comment: [**is-there-way-to-keep-delimiter-while-using-php-explode-or-other-similar-function**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938137/is-there-way-to-keep-delimiter-while-using-php-explode-or-other-similar-function)

Comment: @Shiro nope i did not downvote, in this context, yes because after you exploded the delimiter will not be included

Comment: @mithunsatheesh thanks for the link thats what i wanted

Comment: You'd need to use some sort of regex pattern to pick it up and keep the delimeter

Comment: There are some idiots on this site who are just playing the idiotic repo game..!! I think they are getting paid for down voting other queries and answers. isn't it..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of [regex lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) should do it:

```
<?php

$input = "The address is http://stackoverflow.com/";
$parts = preg_split('@(?=http://)@', $input);
var_dump($parts);
```

This would output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "The address is"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "http://stackoverflow.com/"
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it indeed helps, thanks a lot