# explode and preg_match_all keep delimiter

Tags: php, explode, preg-match-all

I split first my string with explode.

```
$split= explode('Cars:', $string);
echo $split[0]; // first
echo $split[1]; // second
```

So but i want to keep the word "Cars:".

I try that.

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\w*Cars:\w*)\b/',
$string,
$split, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $split[0][0] . ", " . $split[0][1] . "\n";
echo $split[1][0] . ", " . $split[1][1] . "\n";
```

So what i need is i need to split a string in two parts.
But i want to keep the delimiter.

My string is every time different, but here a example:

```
Price:  $3,995
Mileage:    100,753 miles
Transmission:   Manual
Exterior Color: Blue
Interior Color: Black
Engine: I4
Other Cars: Car 1, Car 2, Car 3
```

Other Cars: is a list of recommended cars. (Hyperlinks)

**UPDATE:**
I got now that. But how can i use also : ? So Cars:

```
preg_split('/\b(\w*Cars\w*)\b/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Please post the string which you want to split.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938137/is-there-way-to-keep-delimiter-while-using-php-explode-or-other-similar-function refer this link

Comment: Oh, it is the same pattern you used before - `preg_split('~\b(Cars:)~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`